# Oracle how to print some message?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

As we know in MSSQL we can write below line to print some message

```
print 'Some Message';
```

How we can do same in Oracle as print not working with Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Some Message');
```

Comment: If your client/application supports it, and you've done `set serveroutput on` or its equivalent... this [writes to a buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm), and you need something that consumes the buffer. SQL*Plus handles it for you, of course, but this might be needed somewhere else. I'm sure this is what the OP needs, but sometimes it isn't as straightforward as this suggests.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @mhasan's answer and @AlexPoole's comment: assuming that you're executing your script using SQL*Plus you'll need to add the beginning of your script before the first DECLARE or BEGIN:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET LINESIZE 255
```

If you're using a tool other than SQL*Plus to run your script there will be different ways to view output written to DBMS_OUTPUT. For example, in PL/SQL Developer a "Test" window has a "DBMS Output" tab where text written to DBMS_OUTPUT can be viewed after the test script terminates.

Share and enjoy.